# Cypress can not detect the alias and parse it as a node module error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, cypress, alias

When I try to e2e testing for the project I got below error.
My project is composed of Nextjs and typescript, redux.

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./deprecated/redux/store.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/helpers/isServer' in 'E:\SampleWorkingProjects\redux'
resolve '@/helpers/isServer' in 'E:\SampleWorkingProjects\redux'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: E:\SampleWorkingProjects\package.json (relative path: ./deprecated/redux)
    resolve as module
      E:\SampleWorkingProjects\redux\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      E:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules
        using description file: E:\SampleWorkingProjects\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: E:\SampleWorkingProjects\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@/helpers/isServer)
            no extension
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer doesn't exist
            .js
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.js doesn't exist
            .json
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.json doesn't exist
            .jsx
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.jsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.mjs doesn't exist
            .coffee
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.coffee doesn't exist
            .ts
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer.tsx doesn't exist
            as directory
              E:\SampleWorkingProjects\node_modules\@\helpers\isServer doesn't exist
```

I think this is because the cypress can not parse the alias @.
Below is my plugin file

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
// module.exports = (on, config) => {
//   // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
//   // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
// }
const injectDevServer = require('@cypress/react/plugins/next');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  injectDevServer(on, config);

  return config;
};
```

I didn't add any webpack config file to the project.
But it contains cypress, typescript and next config.

Comment: Are there any updates for this?